# Should ViewController-Presenter-Interactor have one to one relationship

Tags: ios, mvp, viper-architecture

I am reading about VIPER and my understanding is- generally a viewController is related to one presenter and one presenter talks to one Interactor.

But, what if we have master-details pages or list-detail pages. To display list of items, I would have one controller/Presenter to display list and another controller/presenter to display details. And FetchList and FetchDetail should belong to same interactor.

If these two presenters communicate to this interactor, they would have to implement both the methods FetchList and FetchDetail. And one of these two method's implementation would be empty.

Answer (score 2):

You should have two separate VIPER modules: MainItems and DetailedItems.

Read this post (https://www.ckl.io/blog/best-practices-viper-architecture) and see how to use delegates to send data between VIPER modules. Note that `FetchList` and `FetchDetail` should belong to **different** interactor:

```html
// 1. Declare which messages can be sent to the delegate

// ProductScreenDelegate.swift
protocol ProductScreenDelegate {
//Add arguments if you need to send some information
    func onProductScreenDismissed()
    func onProductSelected(_ product: Product?)
}

// 2. Call the delegate when you need to send him a message

// ProductPresenter.swift
class ProductPresenter {

    // MARK: Properties
    weak var view: ProductView?
    var router: ProductWireframe?
    var interactor: ProductUseCase?
    var delegate: ProductScreenDelegate?
}

extension ProductPresenter: ProductPresentation {

    //View tells Presenter that view disappeared
    func onViewDidDisappear() {

        //Presenter tells its delegate that the screen was dismissed
        delegate?.onProductScreenDismissed()
    }
}

// 3. Implement the delegate protocol to do something when you receive the message

// ScannerPresenter.swift
class ScannerPresenter: ProductScreenDelegate {

    //Presenter receives the message from the sender
    func onProductScreenDismissed() {

        //Presenter tells view what to do once product screen was dismissed
        view?.startScanning()
    }
    ...
}

// 4. Link the delegate from the Product presenter in order to proper initialize it

// File ScannerRouter.swift
class ProductRouter {

    static func setupModule(delegate: ProductScreenDelegate?) -> ProductViewController {
        ...
        let presenter = ScannerPresenter()

        presenter.view = view
        presenter.interactor = interactor
        presenter.router = router
        presenter.delegate = delegate // Add this line to link the delegate
        ...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you have one view/view-controller and presenter per screen and then one interactor *per use case*, which probably means more than one per screen. This is good practice from the point of view of Single Responsibility Principle and therefore aids testing. But sometimes a concession is made and an interactor handles multiple uses cases.